Unable to use imports from a different folder/Poetry environment on Jenkins
Issue with Poetry and Jenkins: Unable to Use Imports from a different folder/Poetry environment
Hi everyone,
I'm encountering an issue with my current setup involving Poetry and Jenkins. I'm trying to implement Poetry in my scripts and run them on Jenkins, so far no luck (first time using Poetry).

Directory Structure
Here is a simplified version of my directory structure:
top_level/
├── helpers/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── helper_function.py
│   ├── poetry.lock
│   └── poetry.toml
│   └── pyproject.toml
|
└── xx/
    └── xx/
        └── xx/
            └── src/
                ├── script.py
                └── poetry.lock
                ├── poetry.toml
                └── pyproject.toml

This is what the poetry.toml looks like:
[virtualenvs]
create = true
in-project = true
prefer-active-python = false


Problem
I'm running scripts from the top_level/xx/xx/xx/src directory and trying to use some helper functions located in the top_level/helpers directory. However, the scripts cannot recognise the imports from the helpers directory.
Here is the Jenkins pipeline script I'm using (Poetry is already installed on the node) and it's already at the top_level directory:
groovy
stage('Install Dependencies and Execute Script') {
    steps {
        ansiColor('xterm') {
            script {
                sh """
                # Install dependencies for helpers
                cd helpers
                poetry install --no-root
                
                # Back to the top_level directory
                cd ..

                # Export PYTHONPATH to include helpers directory
                export PYTHONPATH="\$PWD/helpers"

                # Install dependencies for the project
                cd xx/xx/${folderName}
                poetry install --no-root
                
                # Run the script with Poetry
                echo "Running the script..."
                poetry run python -u src/main.py
                """
            }
        }
    }
}


Question
How can I properly configure Poetry and my project structure so that the scripts in the src directory can recognise and import the helper functions from the helpers directory on Jenkins?
Is it possible to have multiple Poetry environments?
Any advice or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
Attempt
On paper this should work (?) however still imports from helpers folder do not get recognised.

One way could be sys.path.insert() in the python so the script would find the path for the library you want to use
